# Understanding vertex buffer and index buffer in game engines

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine, vertex-buffer, turbulenz

I am new to game engines. I started reading about html5 browser games recently since turbulenz engine became open sourced.

Its not difficult to grasp the javascript code and the concepts from the samples. I just wanted to know **how the vertex buffers and index buffers work in any game engine and how they are useful**

I have pasted a very simple example [here](http://pastebin.com/EjnzvCw0). When I modify the data in *vertexBufferParameters* variable, the box gets twisted etc etc. I couldn't understand how the vertex buffers and index buffers affect the rendering of the box.

Any relevant links on understanding these buffers would also be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Google? Read this http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification and this http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=28

Comment: And most important: Don't use engine, when you want to learn low-level features of the platform. The purpose of an engine is to hide low-level features.

Answer (score 1):

Looking here at the rather concise notes from one of my lecturers a few years back:

[Polygon Meshes](http://glasnost.itcarlow.ie/~powerk/GeneralGraphicsNotes/meshes/polygon_meshes.html)

You can see that in the Data Structures for Representing a Mesh section there is alot of information relevant to the topic, particularly the section on index to vertex lists. The entire document is well worth a read as a primer for this:

[Index and Vertex Buffers](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/index-and-vertex-buffers)

This shows the use of the buffers, and their application in graphics. Essentially, a vertex list is a list of the coordinates (2d/3d) of each point on each triangle in say a square. Drawing these without an index list, some of these vertexes are repeated, unnecessarily. An index list is a 'quick reference' to the vertexes, and when drawing more complex shapes becomes quite a time saver.